# Xamarin Mac - Process execution "Write Fault on Path"

Tags: macos, xamarin, process, xamarin.mac, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to install HomeBrew (https://brew.sh/) from my Xamarin Mac App.

The process is quite Simple, like:

```
 /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

So, to perform it from my App, I'm trying with "System.Diagnostic.Process" like this:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startinfo.WorkingDirectory = "/usr/local";
        startinfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startinfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        startinfo.FileName = "/usr/bin/ruby";
        startinfo.Arguments = @" -e ""$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)""";
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startinfo;

        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.Start();

        while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine());

        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
        process.WaitForExit();
        Console.ReadKey();
```

the OUTPUT I get is:

```
 -e:1: `$(' is not allowed as a global variable name
```

If I run the same operation in Terminal, everything works fine.
If I try to perform something basic like:

```
ls -l
```

I get a strange error:

```
       System.IO.IOException
       Write fault on path /Users/[USER]/Projects/_git/[FOLDER]/bin/Debug/[APPNAME]/Contents/Resources/[Unknown]
```

What's wrong? I have to perform some "automatic interactions" so I'll need to run simple commands like this. Do I need some other "capacity"?

Comment: Is this a `Xamarin.Mac` (Cocoa) based application or a .Net console app as your are using `ReadKey` but referring to `Xamarin.Mac`? And if it is a `Xamarin.Mac` app, is it sandboxed (i.e. A Store-based app?)

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks! It's a Xamarin.Mac (Cocoa), it's not sandboxed and won't go on the store